# How do you make Dreamweaver's screen bigger?

Tags: dreamweaver

I use dreamweaver on my laptop and the words are too small. Is there like a zoom in button I can use? I can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your resolution i may help

Answer (score 1):

In design view there is a scale view option on the bottom of the window (100% size up to 6400%).
In code view i'm pretty sure there is an option in the preferences to choose font-size of code.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS you would use ctrl+mousewheel.